# How do I create a Feat with charges in D&D Beyond?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, homebrew, dnd-beyond

I'm trying to create a homebrew feat on D&D Beyond that allows the PC to cast two different spells, in any combination, a total of 5 times per day. The specific spells are **not** the important part, it's the total of 5 times per day part that is. Currently, I have the two spells being able to be cast 5 times per day, each.

With a magic item, you can design the item with 5 charges, and then specify the number of charges that each spell consumes. How can you do the same thing with a feat?

I chose a feat for narrative purposes. I could easily make a magic item that has the desired effects, but an item isn't as ... permanent as a feat is. This is a variation of the Dark Gifts concept from Van Richten's Guide to Ravenloft, and as such is not something a character can just toss in a ditch.

**How do I create a Feat with charges in D&D Beyond?**

Comment: I don't see why this question should be opinion-based. It is a technical question concerning D&D Beyond. There has to be an objective answer. Either: "This is impossible" or "Here's how you can do this". I mean the question has a lot of extra bits of information but that doesn't make it opinion-based.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To give a feat "charges", you do so under either the spells or actions section when you add the spell or action. Since your feat is not calling on specific spells, your best bet would be to create a "general" action and fill it out with the important details and restrictions about your feat's usage. Then, at the bottom of that form, under "Limited Use", create a limited use of "5".

If your feat does call for specific spells, make sure those spells have no value set for "Number of Uses", as this will override the general "Limited Use" setting on the feat.

You can easily do something like copy the Lucky feat - a feat with charges - and just change the details to match your feat instead.

[image: Example of adding charges to a feat]

Comment: The 'Limited Use' was exactly what I needed, TY for finding that!! I'd suggest adding to your answer that you need to make sure that any spells associated with the feat do NOT have a 'Number of Uses' assigned to them. If you specify a spell having such, it overwrites the Limited Use feature of the Actions section. As this feat does call on specific spells, it was important to have them - which spells they were just didn't matter for the question.